# Calculating factorial using Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I was reading a code sample that calculates the factorial using Lisp as below:

```
(defun fatorial (n)
  (cond
    ((= n 1) 1)
    (t (* n (fatorial (- n 1))))))
```

So, I was wondering what is `t` in this code sample? Does it have any special meaning in Lisp? I searched but couldn't find my answer!

Comment: I guess that you named your function `fatorial` because it results in a `fat` stack footprint.

Comment: Wrong guess! In Spanish, Factorial is written : Fatorial ! ;)

Comment: What? ... In spanish, _factorial_ is written... "factorial". Anyway, I suppose the stack always behave like this for recursion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's the symbol LISP uses for True. In a `cond` in LISPs, the "catch all" at the end uses `t` to indicate that if none of the preceding conditions evaluate to True, this code will always execute.

Consider it here as the equivalent of an `else` in an if-else. On the whole, though, it just represents True.

Answer (score 3):

A cond consists of the `cond` symbol followed by a number of cond clauses, each of which is a list. The first element of a cond clause is the condition; the remaining elements (if any) are the action. The cond form finds the first clause whose condition evaluates to true (ie, doesn't evaluate to nil); it then executes the corresponding action and returns the resulting value.

So, in your code, the firs test checks if n equals 1 and, if so, returns 1. The other clause, starting with "t" (for true in lisp) is the "else" part of the condition.